# Validity of formulas in very specific alphabet

Tags: first-order-logic

> Let $\Sigma = \{c_1, c_2, R(\cdot,\cdot)  \}$ be an alphabet in first-order logic without $=$, where $c_1,$ $c_2$ are constant variables and $R$ is binary relation.
> Let $\varphi$ be a formula without quantifiers such that $FV(\varphi)=\{x\}$.
>
> Prove or disprove:
> if the first-order sentence $\exists \,x\,\varphi(x)$ is valid, then there exists a variable $s$ ($s\in\{c_1,c_2\}$) such that $\varphi[s/x]$ is valid.

I tried to both prove and disprove, in both cases I failed.
When I tried to disprove, I tried to think of formulas $\varphi$ such that $\exists \,x\varphi(x)$ were valid, but for such formulas the claim was indeed correct.

So I tried to prove, I had an idea to use Herbrand model and the ground instances to come to some conclusion, but I could not move on from there.

I tried other things but I do not speak English and it is difficult for me to translate everything I tried. I really appreciate the helpers!

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sentence
$$
(R(c_1,c_1) \lor R(c_2,c_2)) \to R(x,x).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a specific way to come up with such example? Or it was just intuition

Comment: I tried to think how a proof might work. The case of disjunction wasn’t clear.